# Laravel при создании своей страницы ошибка 404

Tags: laravel

что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было добавить свою страницу на фреймворке Laravel? При добавлении любой страницы при переходе на её адрес пишет 404 ошибку

Comment: Добавить роут на страницу в `routes/web.php`

Comment: Не могу найти этот файл, где он может хранится?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, у меня использовалась версия Laravel хз какая, но ниже 5.4 что-ли и у меня маршруты прописываюстя в `/app/http/routes.php`, а не в `/routes/web.php`